# how to navigate one page to another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I am trying to make simple app in backbone .Actually I want to call methods when url change .I want to learn how backbone routing works .I studied routing  but my alert is not display when I change the url .
When I append the url with this **“#contacts”** but it is not calling this method

```
listContacts: function () {
          alert("route")
            console.log("route to list contacts was triggered");
            ContactsApp.List.Controller.listContacts();
        }
```

Can we move to next page or view while click to any item of list .Actually I want to move one page to another after click of row using backbone routing ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/yN16uPgk0dcJAcrApewH?p=preview

```
app.module("ContactsApp", function (ContactsApp, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
   // console.log(app)
    ContactsApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            "contacts": "listContacts"
        }
    });
    var API = {
        listContacts: function () {
          alert("route")
            console.log("route to list contacts was triggered");
            ContactsApp.List.Controller.listContacts();
        }
    };
    ContactsApp.on("start", function () {
        new ContactsApp.Router({
            controller: API
        });
    });
});
```

any update  using marionette?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Backbone Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
  'main': '#main1'
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'item(/*id)': 'item',
    '*params': 'home'
  }
});

app.router = new Router();

// Home route
app.router.on('route:home', function() {
  var page = new HomeView({...})
  app.main.show(page);
});

// Item route
app.router.on('route:item', function(id) {
  var page = new ItemView({id:id, ...})
  app.main.show(page);
});

...

app.start();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Here is your [modified code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qMLGUu4kjlVSVUEiolVP?p=preview).

Comment: yes I know that but how I will use that ..could you please give one example ..on button click I move to next page

Comment: Please see link in the end.

Comment: Thanks for answer you are using backbone routing can we use marionette routing http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.approuter.html

Comment: It works the same way and uses Backbone Router as well, just little different syntax.

Comment: can do some favour for me  can you make one plunker using that ?

Comment: any chance to use marionette rounting ?